# Need advice on whether or not to fix a laptop that has been damaged

Tags: laptop-repair

I know it is hard to give a good answer without being to able inspect damage, so all I really seek is advice.

The victim: Lenovo Yoga 700-14isk (2 months old  RIP)

About 2 years ago, my fiance had a car accident which sent her and and several of her belongings out the window (she is good). One of the objects that flew was her pretty new laptop. We haven't touched it since then since at the time i found the screens costing more.

Recently I decided to undertake some laptop repair of my own and decided to look into her screen again. Now my question is, is it worth fixing?

The screen is broken and needs to be replaced, nothing can be seen from it. But if you charge the laptop  it runs fine, and according to several shops she took it to, it runs (you can check via hdmi, but I haven't had a chance myself because I do not have a micro hdmi).

Anyways, u have opened it up and seen the internals myself, and aside from the motherboard being slightly bent I see no damage (aside from the fact that the ssd is probably damaged from the impact).

So my question is: if I fire it up, plug in an hdmi and it works, should I spend the money on a screen to fix it, or will it most likely fail on us quickly from unseen damage? Money isn't the issue, spending it on a lost cause is.

Comment: If it works fine when connected to an external display, that confirms that on all likelihood only the screen need to be replaced. But without touching it that's just ash educated guess.

Comment: Connect it to your home tv and use for youtube, film streaming etc you risk money on something probably unreliable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy or borrow a cheap HDMI adapter.  You can't know anything until you can hook it up to a working screen.  If it still starts up and the HDMI output works, then you've got a lot of diagnostics ahead of you.

I'm assuming you don't want to spend a ton of money on spare parts beyond a new screen, and that you're willing to spend maybe a few hours a day for a week on this, tops (not counting time waiting for new parts).

If it no longer boots, check for overheating first (easiest to fix).  Then if the SSD is standard and replacable, try a new SSD.  If it won't boot and neither of those easy fixes does the trick, you're done, sell it for parts.

If it boots, then run every diagnostic test you can think of.  Make sure all the ports still work.  Make sure all of the keys on the keyboard still work. Test the trackpad.  Run a RAM test for 6 or 8 hours while you do other stuff.  Run a CPU torture test overnight, and then a GPU torture test all day while you are at work.  Make a list of parts that you need to replace, and look on Ebay for prices.  If the number of things needing to be replaced gets too pricey for your budget, then stop and sell it for parts.

If you experience any error messages, or get unexplained restarts or shutdowns, then check for overheating, and if that isn't the problem, it's spare parts.

If it overheats, make sure the fan is able to spin without obstruction and without noise at idle. Take it apart and renew the thermal compound between the CPU/GPU and the heatsink. If neither of those things fixes the overheating, it's spare parts.  If the case or frame is bent and is pinning the fan or blocking the vents, check replacement part prices, but most likely it's a lost cause.

If it passes all the tests, does not need parts you aren't willing to buy, and does not suffer from unexplained shutdowns during torture testing, then run a really long torture test (two full days, or longer).  If it passes that, it's probably safe to repair the screen and put it back in service.